# Changing maven build output directory for .jar (has dependencies)

Tags: eclipse, maven, bukkit

I'm setting up eclipse again to make plugins for bukkit, which is an API that i depend on. Also i want to move the .jar the build process creates to a directory of my choice.

http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#Commands (makes the pom.xml below)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MY_PACKAGE_NAME</groupId>
  <artifactId>MY_PLUGIN_NAME</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>bukkit-repo</id>
      <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
      <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.9-R0.2</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Current output:

```
$project_root/target/MY_PLUGIN_NAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Desired output:

```
C:/my/output/directory/MY_PLUGIN_NAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following configuration under `<build>` tag:

```
 <outputDirectory>C:/my/output/directory</outputDirectory>
```

**tip / warning :**  Although this will work but keeping your packaging outside target is discouraged. Its not maven standard.  Rethink before doing it.